# PHP breadcrumb class

Tags: beginner, php, object-oriented

I am fresh at OOP and I am curious if the code below is object oriented and can be improved:

```
class cTitleBreadcrumb {

public function __construct($sAction, $sItem){
    $this->sAction = $sAction;
    $this->sItem = $sItem;
}

public function displayAction(){
    if($this->checkUrlAction($this->sAction) === true){     
        return $this->sAction;
    }
}
public function displayItem(){
    if($this->checkUrlItem($this->sItem) === true){
        return $this->sItem;
    }
}       
private function checkUrlAction($sAction){

    if($sAction == 'insert' || $sAction == 'view' || $sAction == 'update' || $sAction == 'delete'){         
        return true;
    }
}

private function checkUrlItem($sItem){
    if($sItem == 'imagelist' || $sItem == 'mkdir' || $sItem == 'rdir'){
        return true;
    }
    else{       
        $objShowPDO = new mShowPDO();
        $result = $objShowPDO->allTables();     
        while($array = $result->fetch()){
            if($array[0] == $this->sItem){
                return true;
            }
        }       
    }
}



$objTitleBreadcrumb = new cTitleBreadcrumb($sAction,$sItem);

echo ucfirst($objTitleBreadcrumb->displayAction());

echo ucfirst($objTitleBreadcrumb->displayItem());
```

Answer (score 1):

### You are not always returning anything

```
private function checkUrlAction($sAction) {
    if(true){         
        return true;
    }

    //but else?
}
```

### Dependency injection

$objShowPDO = new mShowPDO(); is bad a mShowPDO instance should by injected via method or constructor argument see dependency injection topics

```
private function checkUrlItem(mShowPDO $objShowPDO, $sItem){
    if($sItem == 'imagelist' || $sItem == 'mkdir' || $sItem == 'rdir'){
        return true;
    }

    //redundand else removed

    $result = $objShowPDO->allTables(); //maybe you can inject only the result
    while($array = $result->fetch()){
        if($array[0] == $this->sItem){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

### Hard coding

The checklists are really hard coded (long if with OR relations), try use some container for them (an array and use in_array() for example).

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply. What do you mean by You are not always returning anything and whats the solution for this dependency injection?

Comment: He means that for the display functions you should always return something.  If the sAction doesn't pass your check you don't return anything from `displayAction()` (and same for displayItem).

Comment: @Peter, do you mean like mysql_real_escape_string for mysql_*?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand how the mysql_ stuff comes here.

Comment: ahh ok i understand thanks. But i dont understand the PDO Dependency injection, can you explain it, whats exactly the problem and how can code it correctly?

Comment: See this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Answer (score 1):

Just little improvement to write this method shorter

```
private function checkUrlAction($sAction)
{
    return in_array($sAction , array('insert','view','update''delete'));
}
```

Comment: A recommend to put the array in a class field.

Comment: @Peter put an array in a class field, what do you mean by that?

Comment: class cTitleBreadcrumb { private $_actions = array(...) } and then in the return statement: return in_array($sAction, $this->_actions));

Comment: ahh ok i understand thanks. 
But i dont understand the PDO Dependency injection, can you explain it, whats exactly the problem and how can code it correctly?